# Conversion from decrypted NSData to NSDictionary fails

Tags: objective-c, encryption, nsstring, aes

I have to encrypt and scramble a `NSDictionary` and then unscramble and decrypt in another method. I have followed the instructions from [Securely storing keys in iOS Application](https://sites.google.com/site/greateindiaclub/mobil-apps/ios/securelystoringoauthkeysiniosapplication) **except** that I'm **not using a PLIST file** to fill the `NSDictionary` values, but `NSString` values that are being inputed in the program and I'm doing this targeting **OSX**

The program can be divided in 3 parts:

- **Encryption**: Encrypts the NSDictionary and returns a base64encoded `NSString`
- **Scramble**: Scrambles the base64encoded key among the values of the previous `NSString`
- **Unscramble and Decryption**

My problem is in the last decryption. The unscramble works just fine, but the decryption seems to produce `NSData` that can't be convertible into the original `NSDictionary`

#### Encryption

What I'm doing for **encryption** is:

- Initialising a `NSDictionary`
- Converting it to `NSData` via `NSPropertyListSerialization` and format `NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0`
- Encrypting this data using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) and a key
- Returning the **base64** representation of this `NSData` as `NSString`

The code for this part is:

```
+(NSString *)encrypt:(NSString *)firstValue secondValue:(NSString *)secondValue andKey:(NSString *)key;
{
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstValue, secondValue, nil] forKeys:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"first", @"second", nil]];
  NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:nil];
  NSData *encryptData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:key error:nil];

  return [encryptData base64EncodedString];
}
```

#### Scramble

The second part of the process is to scramble the key in **base64** among the characters of the data, I'm doing this by:

- Converting the key to `NSData` using `-(NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:`
- Converting this `NSData` to a base64encoded `NSString`
- Inserting `char` of this `NSString` into a `NSMutadedString` in a particular order
- Returning `NSString` from this `NSMutadedString` to be decrypted later

Here's the code for the **scramble** part:

```
+(NSString *)scrambleStrings:(NSString *)firstValue secondValue:(NSString *)secondValue andKey:(NSString *)key;
{
  NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  key = [keyData base64EncodedString];

  // String from the first method
  NSString *encrypt = [self encrypt:firstValue secondValue:secondValue andKey:key];

  NSArray *myOrder = [self mySortAlgorithm:key];

  NSMutableString *mutableEncrypt = [NSMutableString stringWithString:encrypt];

  for(int i=0; i<[myOrder count];i++)
  {
    unichar c = [key characterAtIndex:i];
    int index = [[myOrder objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    [mutableEncrypt insertString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1] atIndex:index];
  }

  return [NSString stringWithString:mutableEncrypt];
}
```

#### Decryption

The third part consists of testing if I can decrypt and unscramble it to the original `NSDictionary` and `NSString` key. It basically consists of:

- Retrieve the scrambled `NSString` from the second method
- Separating the scrambled key from the dictionary `NSData` from the previous `NSString`
- Decode the base64encode key (Works for sure 'till here)
- Decode the base64encoded dictionary data
- Decrypt the previous data using `RNCryptor` using the decoded key
- Initialising a `NSDictionary` using the data from the last step
- Output the `NSDictionary` values via `NSLog`

And Here's the code for this last part:

```
+(BOOL)testScrambleWithFirstValue:(NSString *)firstValue secondValue:(NSString *)secondValue andKey:(NSString *)key;
{
   NSString *scrambledAndEncryptedKeys = [self scrambleFirstValue:firstValue secondValue:SecondValue andKey:key];

   NSArray *myOrder = [self mySortAlgorithm:key];

   NSMutableString *encryptedDictionary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
   NSMutableString *encryptedKey = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

   for (int i=0; i<scrambledAndEncryptedKeys.length; i++) {

     char c = [scrambledAndEncryptedKeys characterAtIndex:i];

     if ([myOrder doesContain:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]]) {
        [encryptedKey appendFormat:@"%c", c];
      } else {
        [encryptedDictionary appendFormat:@"%c",c];
      }
    }

    NSString *decryptedKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:[NSString stringWithString:encryptedKey]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64DataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:[NSString stringWithString:encryptedDictionary]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:[base64DataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withPassword:decryptedKey error:nil];

    NSPropertyListFormat xmlFormat;

    NSDictionary *decryptedDictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:decryptedData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&xmlFormat error:nil];

    //Outputs NULL
    NSLog(@"decryptedDictionary:%@", decryptedDictionary);

    //Just to simplify I'm returning YES here
    return YES;
}
```

The problem is, that the last `NSLog` outputs a `NULL` value. Which makes me think that the `NSData` is not being decrypted.

I've been hammering my head over this since yesterday morning, so all the help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you "scrambling"?  I'd suggest you break your problem in half and get encrypt/decrypt to work by itself and get your scramble/unscramble (if you really feel you need it) to work by itself, then combine them.

Comment: The decrypt and unscramble part is going to be used in another program, so yes, I'm already breaking in two. The test is merely for this question and there's no problem in the scramble part, since I can retrieve and decode my key properly.

Comment: So encrypt/decrypt works by itself and scramble/unscramble works by itself, they just don't work when combined???

Comment: The decrypt doesn't Seem to work. The main problem is that I can't convert back to the NSDictionary. I used another aes encryption library and the result was just the same, the NSDictionary outputs null just the same

Comment: Is the result off with the first byte, or only bad towards the end?

Comment: Your comment actually made me come to an interesting conclusion. The first byte is ok, but only this one! The rest of the NSString is kind of shifted! The error must be at inserting characters at the NSMutableString. I'm pursuing now other approaches. Thanks in advance